# Does shake reduction take focusing distance into account?

Tags: image-stabilization, camera-shake

Does shake reduction take focusing distance into account? For big enough magnifications correcting camera shift (as opposed to tilt) becomes necessary for obtaining sharp image. What shake reduction systems use focusing distance to correct camera shift for macro photos?

[image]

Comment: Shake reduction systems that consider focusing distance can correct for camera shift more effectively than systems that do not. This is because they can compensate for the different amount of camera shift that occurs at different focusing distances.

Some shake reduction systems that use focusing distance to correct camera shift for macro photos include:

Canon's Image Stabilization
Nikon's Vibration Reduction
Sony's SteadyShot
Olympus's Sync IS

Answer (score 3):

The `Canon EF 100mm f/2.8L Macro IS USM`, from [the description](https://www.usa.canon.com/shop/p/ef-100mm-f-2-8l-macro-is-usm?color=Black&type=New):

> This is the first lens on the market to incorporate Canon's new Hybrid Image Stabilization Technology. Hybrid IS effectively compensates for both angular and shift camera shake during close-up shooting. The lens was developed to expand users' photographing range and allow a wider range of users to easily enjoy macro photography.

The `Canon EF-S 35mm f/2.8 Macro IS STM` and `Canon EF-M 28mm f/3.5 Macro IS STM` are also described has having a "Hybrid IS".

My experience is that when shooting handled macro, your worst enemy is a longitudinal move that invalidates the focus.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to start from the assumption that the significant shake mode is camera shift, meaning that the camera moves sideways without changing its orientation. For this shake mode, your reasoning is correct.

While surely such shake can occur, in most real-world scenarios a different mode of shake dominates, in that the camera orientation changes while its center of gravity stays more or less stable. For the effects of this shake mode, the focusing distance is irrelevant, only the focal length (together with the pixel size) matters.

Answer (score 0):

Lens based image stabilization takes magnification (focal length) into account as part of the lens design.

And lens based stabilization is better suited for greater magnifications because it occurs farther away from the image plane... due to its' distance, a small shift creates a larger correction.

Sensor based stabilization takes into account angular displacement of the image plane AND magnification (at least Nikon Z's do). Unfortunately, due to size and other design considerations, sensor based stabilization is not well suited for the large corrections high magnification may require (limited range/speed). That's why they are still making lenses with optical stabilisation to use/integrate with bodies that have IBIS.

Correction for focus *distance* is not necessary (as opposed to magnification).

The drawing doesn't make much sense to me; you cannot have an object at a greater distance occupying the same FOV without an *increase* in magnification... the opposite of your question. But I do understand the intent... greater magnification does cause greater image displacement (regardless of what causes the increased magnification).